# Lightweight Java IDE that Maintains Indentation?

Tags: java, ide, auto-indent

Whenever I am debugging a java program, I have to have the code indented! And I hate to manually indent code one by one (using Tab).

I would really like a lightweight Java IDE that automatically indents ALL your code at a push of a button.

A good example is "Ready To Program" Java IDE, but the downside to this IDE is that it is not compatible with JDK 1.5+

Are there any suggestions on such a Java IDE?

Comment: Netbeans does it too but same as @OscarRyz no "light weight"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IntellJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_style.html) and [Eclipse](http://www.peterfriese.de/formatting-your-code-using-the-eclipse-code-formatter/) come to my mind.

I wouldn't call Eclipse light weight though.

Comment: I would :) it ran on my Pentium II :)

Comment: Eclipse is also much more powerful than NPP as I suggested. If OP wants to fine tune how it gets formatted it's a great choice. No experience with IDEA so I couldn't comment.

Comment: +1 for IntelliJ - it's the best IDE out there, hands down.  Eclipse 1.0 might have run on a Pentium II, but it's become a bloating Frankenstein monster since then.

Answer (score 1):

I use Notepad++ for quick indentation. It's called "Reindent C++ code" but it works just as well for Java code.

http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: Notepad++ is also a great choice (in my opinion). But I'm just too lazy to compile my programs through command prompt.

Comment: I find that anything non-trivial has a build script I run from prompt anyway. :-p I also will often fire it up just for it's html or c++ beautifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Factor` option in [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/) to properly format/indent your Java code.  It's even got a handy shortcut: `Alt+Shift+F`

Edit: Oh yeah, Netbeans is great, but not really lightweight...

Answer (score 0):

In the good old days, I used to use emacs as an "IDE" for Java development.  It has excellent support for code indentation and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Coding Java in NPP must be similar experience to shaving yourself with blunt stone and using vodka instead of aftershave. It may look manly, but there's no reason. It's XXI century. Intellij will run on any reasonable PC, same with NetBeans and Eclipse.

Those features are no-brainer for me, along with about hundred of others. Build in debugger with ability to execute any piece of code, or checking variable state are also necessary. I know that most of debugger may be replaced with good suite of unit tests, however sometimes you just need to check something live.

And as we are on topic of unit tests, even that is possible to simplify with good IDE. Intellij allows you to navigate between class and test class, run single test, whole class or suite with simple key stroke, generate test method from template, etc.

If you live from writing code, then don't do it to yourself and just buy a license, or use open version. Life is to short to work on NPP with plugins.

Disclaimer: Vim is okay, if you have to reconfigure something on live system in order to save a lot of $$$, c's it'll take time to deploy new version. In any other case, using advanced notepad is just stupid. Why? For same reason as coding not on decent hardware but on OLPC.